# compile Chromium with Extensions and command line switchs

Tags: c++, chromium

**Question 1:**
I want to compile Chromium with extensions so that they update from the WebStore.
I can do this with a local extension via a crx-file. But then it will not be updated.

**Question 2:**
Where can I initialize the command line key kDisableWebSecurity?
I understand that I have to write

```
command_line->AppendSwitch(switches::kDisableWebSecurity)
```

.But where? Which file?

Comment: Extensions must be installed from the Chrome web store to be updatable from there

Comment: I'm sure there is an opportunity to set the url in source Chromium to the extension in the WebStore.